# Method must have a return type and Invalid Token '=' C# MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First, I am fairly new to MVC. I am using VS2012, created a basic MVC Application. I am trying to make a Dropdown menu from an existing database table called "Schools". I did this by:

> create a folder in solution
>   Create a class

I, then, put the code below and I got 5 error messages:

- Method must have a return type
- Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
- Error 3 The type or namespace name 'InternshipProgramEntities_db' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- Error 5 The name '_db' does not exist in the current context
- Error 4 The name '_db' does not exist in the current context

Can someone please explain what's going on?

[EDIT: solved by fixing the space between _ and db] Thanks a lot!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InternProject;
using InternProject.Models;

namespace InternProject.Classes
{
    public class Utilities
    {
        private readonly static InternshipProgramEntities_db = new InternshipProgramEntities();

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SchoolDropdown()
        {

            var schools = _db.Schools.ToList();

            var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var s in schools)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = s.SchoolName,
                    Value = string.Format("{0}", s.SchoolName)
                }
                );
            }

            return items;
     }
}//end of utilities class
```

Comment: Please do not mark server side code as snippets.

Comment: Looks like you need a space between InternshipProgramEntities and _db

Comment: You miss a space before `_db` in `private readonly static InternshipProgramEntities_db = new InternshipProgramEntities();`

Comment: There should be space between `InternshipProgramEntities_db` as `_db` is the field name for type `InternshipProgramEntities`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private readonly static InternshipProgramEntities_db = new InternshipProgramEntities();
```

should be

```
private readonly static InternshipProgramEntities _db = new InternshipProgramEntities();
```

You forgot to add a space between the class type and instance name